# Нужно ли веб программирование для разработчика на С++?

Tags: обсуждение, диалоги-о-работе

Здравствуйте, занимаюсь программирование около полугода, программирую на с++. Был заказ на сайт, решил разобраться и сделать. Я быстро разобрался в основах и выполнил задачу, так как там было не очень сложно. Сейчас появился ещё один, но намного сложнее. Начал изучать js одновременно с с++ и стараюсь разделять время на оба дела. (Ситуация позволяет учится и практиковаться практически весь день).

На данный момент я не могу точно ответить на то, чем я хочу в будущем заниматься, так как ещё нет каких-то предпочтений и полного понимания индустрии. На примете разработка мобильных приложений либо что-то из системного программирования, непосредвенно веб-разработчиком быть желания нет.

Вопрос таков, имеет ли смысл изучать веб и сможет ли это как-то мне пригодиться в будущем, если я выберу что-то из вышеперечисленного и насколько вообще необходимо (ну или хотя бы как-то помогает) знание веба для программистов на с++ или с#, например. Есть ли какая-то взаимосвязь, или же без цели становится веб программистом изучать это в какой-либо степени не имеет смысла?

Comment: Знание протоколов типа HTTP точно не помешает. Насчет остального - к цыганкам, они, говорят, неплохо будущее предсказывают.

Comment: Как говорил мой дед, "что знаешь и умеешь - за плечами не носить"...

Comment: Немного разбираться в вебе стоит хотя бы потому, что приходится все время лазить по сайтам. А C++ разработчику вообще-то может понадобится что угодно от знания кузнечного дела до выращивания кактусов.

Comment: Ну минусаторы набрели :(

Comment: Пожалуйста, обратите внимание на требования к оформлению вопросов с меткой [meta-tag:диалоги-о-работе] в её описании.

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну не расстраивайся, у всех бывает :)

Answer (score -3):

> Начал изучать js одновременно с с++ и стараюсь разделять время на оба дела. (Ситуация позволяет учится и практиковаться практически весь день).

Вот и классно - учись!

> На данный момент я не могу точно ответить на то, чем я хочу в будущем заниматься, так как ещё нет каких-то предпочтений и полного понимания индустрии.

Тогда просто учи всё что нравится, а дальше будет широкий выбор.
Да и вообще, full stack-разаботчик - это круто :)

> На примете разработка мобильных приложений

Мобильные приложения довольно шасто делаются гибридными - оболочка нативная, а само приложение пишется как web, поднимается сервером на localhost и показывается в webview, встроенном в приложении.

> либо что-то из системного программирования

Ну тут уж вряд ли пригодится. Ну если только знание протокола http, как в комментариях написали.

> непосредвенно веб-разработчиком быть желания нет.

Это пока нет, а потом можешь и передумать :)

Я начинал изучение программирования с Си, потом VB6, ещё позже .NET.
На работу устроился как C#-разработчик, но потом перебрался во frontend.

Да и вообще, все языки интересны по-своему. Иногда возникает желание выучить питон и перл (хотя практической пользы от них не предвидется), но что-то никак не доберусь...

Comment: "Мобильные приложения довольно шасто делаются гибридными" фуфу.

Comment: @Suvitruf, и ничего не фу. Отлично работают, если руки прямые у разработчиков.

Comment: Нативные `WebView` слишком тормозные по своей природе. А если речь про что-то вроде PhoneGap, то тут совсем всё плохо.

Comment: Нет, не тормозные. Речь про нормальные нативные, с PhoneGap'ом не работал.

Comment: Я и с тем, и с тем работал под Android. Не очень приятный опыт.